# Trigger does not set column value as expected

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I have a trigger that updates a column called `value` from a table but when I execute 
the trigger the value of `value` column does not set correctly, it's always set to 0. The trigger is:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER trigger2 
AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_AUX
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 BEGIN
  .....

    IF V_VALUE > 0 THEN       
     /* V_VALUE IS GREATER THAN 0. THIS WORKS FINE */

         SELECT COUNT(*) "NUM" INTO V_NUM
         FROM TABLE1 T1,
          WHERE ............;
         /* V_NUM ALWAYS CONTAINS THE CORRECT VALUE */

         /* THE BUG IS IN THIS UPDATE */
          UPDATE TABLE_UPDATE 
          SET "VALUE" = V_VALUE - V_NUM , FIELD_OK = 'OK' /* ONLY FAILS THE FIRST SET */
          WHERE ID= (SELECT MAX(ID)   
                  FROM TABLE_UPDATE TAB
                  WHERE .....); 

       END IF;    
       .....

END;
```

When I call this trigger previously I have another trigger that insert on a temporary table called `TABLE_AUX` that is:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_UPDATE 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
 ....
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO TABLE_AUX VALUES(....)
END;
```

`TABLE_UPDATE` is the same table used in `trigger2`. Variables `V_VALUE` and `V_NUM` used in `trigger1` are `NUMBER` variables, and `value` column is `NUMBER(30,20)`

Comment: You don't set V_VALUE anywhere in your trigger. What is it? Is it a variable you assign something to or a value in TABLE_AUX?

Comment: So you `insert into table_update` without specifying the `value` or `field_ok` columns; the before-insert trigger fires and inserts into `table_aux`; the after-insert trigger on that is supposed to fire and update the record you just created on `table_update`? And `field_ok` is updated, but `value` is not? Wouldn't this be simpler with a procedure that inserted into both tables with the right values in the first place?

Comment: Assuming you get the current error fixed, are you aware that you're going to get mutating table errors once you are doing anything other than a single-row `INSERT` on `TABLE_UPDATE`?  A row-level trigger on `TABLE_UPDATE` is generally not allowed to modify `TABLE_UPDATE`.

Comment: The only problem I have with my trigger is that "VALUE" column isn't updated when I call Trigger2. Trigger1 works fine and it doesn´t matter what fields I insert into table_aux. For example, if V_VALUE = 3 and V_NUM = 0 it sets into "VALUE" 3, but if V_VALUE=3 and V_NUM=2 it sets into "VALUE" 0. V_VALUE and V_NUM returns what I expect

Comment: @Idles28 - but it isn't clear if you're inserting `0` and `OK` into `table_update` initially or something else (e.g. nulls); i.e. whether it's updating to 0/OK or if they are already like that and it's not updating at all. Is it finding the `id` you expect, as you may have a race condition - it could update the wrong row? Also, your last comment has a case where it is setting `value` to 3 - before you said it's always 0 - so it is sometimes working?

Comment: in table_update I can insert any values initially, it doesnt matter, nulls too. when I update table_update it works sometimes: when I do V_VALUE - V_NUM and the result is 0 it updates it well, but if the substract is 1,2 or any other value it updates it to 0.

Comment: Besides, the update works well out of the trigger if I test it in a PL/SQL independent script. It fails only inside this trigger. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER trigger2 
AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_AUX
FOR EACH ROW
```

to:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER trigger2 
AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
```

... and then fix the rest of the errors.

Comment: I can´t do it because it causes a mutating table error, and I need to do a trigger so I don't have any other idea but doing my trigger like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your example. Where changes have to be made?

```
CREATE TABLE table_update
(
    id       NUMBER
,   "VALUE"  NUMBER
,   FIELD_OK VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TABLE table_aux
(
    "VALUE"  NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT ON table_update
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_aux("VALUE") VALUES(1);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER trigger2
AFTER INSERT ON table_aux
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_value NUMBER := 100;
    v_num   NUMBER := 10;
BEGIN
    UPDATE  table_update
    SET     "VALUE"  = v_value - v_num
    ,       FIELD_OK = 'OK'
    WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)
                  FROM   TABLE_UPDATE TAB);
END;

INSERT INTO table_update VALUES (1, 1, 'OK');
INSERT INTO table_update VALUES (2, 1, 'OK');
INSERT INTO table_update VALUES (3, 1, 'OK');
INSERT INTO table_update VALUES (4, 1, 'OK');
INSERT INTO table_update VALUES (5, 1, 'OK');

SELECT * FROM table_update;
/*
1   90  OK
2   90  OK
3   90  OK
4   90  OK
5   1   OK
*/

SELECT * FROM table_aux;
/*
1
1
1
1
1
*/
```

Comment: Your example is basically the same I have, the difference is that v_value and v_num are the result of two simple queries. For that reason, I don't understand why it updates me(in you example) 0 instead of 90.

Comment: When you use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE for V_VALUE and V_NUM after the variables are set and before UPDATE what do you see?

Comment: how can you see dbms_output.put_line trace in your IDE?? I am testing the trigger inserting previously in the table_aux table and show set serveroutput on but trace doesnt show

Comment: In my dbms_output appears v_value and v_num several times, like if it was inside a loop

Comment: Are the V_VALUE and V_NUM correct? Is it what you expect to be done?

Comment: RESOLVED! The problem was the declaration of the trigger. I have deleted 'FOR EACH ROW' and then my trigger works fine. Thanks everybody por the answers